# Chrome PDF adds unwanted whitespace after page break

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, pdf, flexbox

The bug appears to happen whenever there is a flex container with descendant elements with the "break-after: avoid" css property. To reproduce, load a page with the following html:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <body>
    <main>
      <div id="header"></div>
      <div id="item-container">
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
      </div>
    </main>
</body>
</html>
```

And the following css:

```css
body {
  background: white;
}

main {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#header {
  height: 100px;
}

.item {
  height: 200px;
  margin: 20px;
  background-color: blue;
  break-inside: avoid;
}
```

A page with this definition is already setup here: https://playcode.io/975516 (open the preview in a new window to print).

This page will render a white page with an empty header of 100px height, followed by several of blue rectangles.

In Chrome, press ctrl + P. When the print options appear, apply the following settings:

- Set Destination to PDF
- Margins = None
- Scale = Default
- Enable Background Graphics

Now, press Save to download the PDF (or you can just look at Print Preview). Notice that there is extra whitespace after every page break. The height of the extra whitespace is equal to the height of the header element, which can lead to especially undesirable layouts. This bug seems specific to Chrome as I cannot reproduce in Firefox or Safari.

Does anyone know of a workaround to avoid this extra whitespace?

Comment: I filed a bug in chrome https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1370349#c3